# Rspec: requiring spec/workers

Tags: ruby, rspec, sidekiq

I've got a bunch of Sidekiq workers in app/workers, and some matching specs in spec/workers. How can I add both to my `rspec` runs? As in stands none are included when I hit up `rspec` on the Terminal.

Comment: Add them to the load path? Usually done in the `spec_helper.rb` or `rails_helper.rb`.

Comment: Am I crazy or are there like _no_ docs on load path syntax?

Comment: How about this in the [manual](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing)? I did not try it, but I am testing workers anyway :-P

Comment: The load path is the Ruby one. You can modify it on the `$:` global variable. Alternatively, you can just `require` each of your worker file with a relative or full path to their files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few alternatives for your situation:

- Rspec loading:

  1. Make sure your test files in `spec/worker` follow the pattern setup for Rspec (e.g. `*.rb` or `*_spec.rb`).
  2. Require the worker files in the `spec_helper.rb`.
- Manual loading: Require the `spec/worker` and `app/worker` files in your `spec_helper.rb` with a Ruby-defined glob.
- Sidekiq helper gem: Add the `rspec-sidekiq` gem to your project, as [explained at Sidekiq's](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing).

To add a bulk of files to the load path, you can either:

- Add path strings to the `$:` global variable, early in your boot process (e.g. at the beginning of `spec_helper.rb`):

`$:.unshift(File.expand_path('../app/workers/**/*_worker.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))`

- Use a glob to load the files without modifying the load path:

```rb
Dir[File.expand_path('../app/workers/**/*_worker.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))].each do |file|
  require file
end
```